# Is SOAP always the message encoding in JAX-WS services?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws

Does the encoding of a message in a JAX-WS service have to use SOAP? Or does JAX-WS simply define the interfaces/contracts (wsdl) but not the encoding?

Comment: SOAP is a whole WebService protocol using a WSDL as a contract between the client and the server. You could use RESTful web services but those do not use WSDLs. Since WSDLs are unique to SOAP.

Comment: Actually, that is not true. JAX-WS has a binding for SOAP but it does not define SOAP which is defined in W3C. It seems like JAX-WS simply defines the mapping between a WSDL and Java objects. The message could then be sent as XML but not necessarily SOAP.

Comment: Hmm, after some research it seems you're right. Sorry for being misleading, I had never seen it used anywhere else and had the impression it was invented exclusively for SOAP usage.

Answer (score 3):

JAX-WS is a framework meant to ease the deployment of Web Services on the server and the client side, relying mostly on annotations. I have never heard of JAX-WS used to deploy anything else than SOAP Web Services and I certainly do not know any JAX-WS implementation that does anything but SOAP.

For REST type Web Services, the corresponding framework is JAX-RS.